# When build android ran into in_app_purchase_android:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, in-app-purchase

I develop flutter with vscode, and use the in app purchase plugin. when I build the project, I ran into Error like this:

> Task :in_app_purchase_android:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac FAILED
> warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
> warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
> warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
> /.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/in_app_purchase_android-0.3.0+13/android/src/test/java/io/flutter/plugins/inapppurchase/InAppPurchasePluginTest.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
> assertEquals("io.flutter.plugins.inapppurchase", BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME);

How can I fix it?

I have updated IAP plugin to latest, but still this error

Comment: You can use this https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase as mentioned by the current dependency you are using.